# Hibernate inheritance error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I am trying to inherit Auditable class to my user class so I can keep track of each user created and updated. But while adding **@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)** its showing me error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

I have tried different solutions for this but I am not able to understand actual reason for this error.

### Auditable.java

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Auditable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    protected String createdBy;
    protected Date createdOn;
    protected String updatedBy;
    protected Date updatedOn;
}
```

### User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends Auditable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String userType;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private Date dob;
    private String email;
}
```

Now while creating new User its not allowing me to save user its showing ClassCaseException. So I am not able to understand how to inherit auditable class.

Comment: Which version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: I think secret is covered in inheritance class which you've chosen. For this type of inheritance to work it will be necessary for database to union tables, which is perfectly possible for entities themselves, but isn't possible  for audit tables. Could you please try to use JOINED strategy?

Comment: @asm0dey I am using Hibernate 4.3.11

Comment: If I am using JOINED then its showing me this error " java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.JoinedSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass"

Comment: please, look at this chapter: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4210
It looks like you should annotate `Auditable` as `@MappedSuperclass`. Do I understand correctly that this class should only provide audit fields to every class which extends it? If yes — than maybe it will make sense to remove id from `Auditable`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two 'id' fields since you are making one table for the object and its superclass.